# C# combobox without autocomplete

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a trivial problem with C# combobox in Windows Forms. I have created a Combobox and I don't want users enter value in it, users should only select values available in it. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change the dropdown style property of the combobox to DropDownList

Answer (score 1):

Set DropDownStyle to `"DropDownList"`

Answer (score 0):

Change dropdownstyle property to dropdownlist.